# ora 20001 error in oracle dbms scheduler

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, plsql, plsql-developer

i have written a test job like

```
begin
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(
job_name => 'test_job'
,job_type =>'plsql_block'
,job_action => 'null'
,enabled => true
);
end;
/
```

after a while when the check the status

```
select * from user_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name='TEST_JOB';
```

the status is failed ,i see these two lines

ORA-20001: You are not allowed to logon from this terminal!!!
ORA-06512: at line 39

how can i resolve this error.
and 
how to find the job id of a scheduled job(created using dbms_scheduler)

Comment: Try logging in from a different terminal, and see [here for Error 06512](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06512.php)

Comment: there is no line 39 in my code.i have only those 10 lines

Comment: Look in Line 39 of the Scheduler, but before you do that fix your login problem...

Comment: I don't know if that is the reason for the error but the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#r4c1-t20) says the job_action value must end with a semicolon

Comment: @E Carter Young: How should he fix the "login problem"? The user should analyze the Oracle source code? useless advice

Comment: 1. create a proper job, plsql_block is not a valid code block. You can use "begin null; end;" if you want to test.
2. in scheduler job, job_id is not important but job_name, which you supplied.
3. There is a logon trigger that is restricting you from logging in, you need to contact your DBAs on finding a workaround or use a dev database with fewer restrictions.

Comment: @Raj "null;" is a valid job_action. See my comment to the answer of MathCurious

Answer (score -1):

Your question contain 2 items that must have been looked at before question itself arose:

1. Have you looked at API of DBMS_SCHEDULER (any programmer should do that before knowing how to use built-in [package]) ; another words have you RTFM?
2. Oracle (most of the time) is in-fact very good with "responses" - error signaling back to "client". Have you googled ora - 20001 ?

To your question:

- Your job action is NULL; you need to have some procedure that does something AND also is not named as Oracle keyword or PLSQl block that must have at bare minimum **begin** and **end**
  [- docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#i1000363)
- Oracle error 20001 is custom error and if you want to see the code you need to contact DBA's.
- Based on the message , seems that your schema also missing some grants (you obviously logged in to the database , so message itself is deceiving , but the exact error can only be identified by going thru the code or checking with DBA's directly - see above )
- why do you need job id? your job name is providing your with information already! check API's!!

Comment: -1 the value of job_action must not be enlosed by `begin ... end;` Read the manual . Apperently the Line does not reference to the users code but the dbms_scheduler package code. I can't see how your answer could help the OP.

Comment: Value for the job_action when **job_type =>'plsql_block'** must be VALID plsql block; which is null is not! if author wanted to go with anonymous plsql block then correct form is **begin null; end;**. Before an error can be analyzed job submission must be properly set! if it compiles , doesn't mean it runs. I've read the manual - have you?

Comment: No, that is not true. "For example, `my_proc();` or `BEGIN my_proc(); END;`"  and " Note that the Scheduler wraps job_action in its own block and passes the following to PL/SQL for execution: `DECLARE ... BEGIN job_action END;`" says the [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm#r4c1-t20). `null;` is a valid job_action if `job_type='PLSQL_BLOCK'`

Comment: indeed **null;** not **null** !!!  do you see **;** in original code? yes - my original statement instead mentioning `must` should've said `should`; but regardless of the way it was articulated there is an error in code, that **must** be addressed before one proceed to analyze the run-time error